# Async function and await keyword

Tags: javascript

Having such a simple js app:

*index.html:*

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app1"></div>
    <div id="app2"></div>
    <div id="app3"></div>
    <div id="app4"></div>

    <script src="src/js1.js"></script>
    <script src="src/js2.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*js1.js:*

```
async function myDisplay() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      myResolve("I love You 1 !!");
    }, 4000);
  });
  document.getElementById("app3").innerHTML = await myPromise;
  document.getElementById("app4").innerHTML = "myDisplay 1";
}

myDisplay();
```

*js2.js:*

```
function myDisplay2() {
  let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      myResolve("I love You 2 !!");
    }, 2000);
  }).then(function (resp) {
    document.getElementById("app1").innerHTML = resp;
  });
  document.getElementById("app2").innerHTML = "myDisplay2";
}

myDisplay2();
```

Why does the function `myDisplay` with the `await` keyword in the *js1.js* script HAVE to be declared as `async` while the function `myDisplay2` in the *js2.j*s script doesn't have?

Comment: Because you are not using the `await`keyword in myDisplay2 :)

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` if you're setting text. use `.textContent`. As for the why: because you're using `await`, which [can only be used inside `async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), which tells the parser that completely different rules apply inside this function body when it comes to data flow and returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside js1.js the function execute a promise that is asynchronous and you want it to wait for the Promise's result :

`document.getElementById("app3").innerHTML = await myPromise;`

At this point, the function will stop and wait for the "myPromise" to complete (resolve or reject).
More on : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

The function inside js2.js do not executes code that block it's execution, myDisplay2 can be executed in a synchrone way, the result of the promise will be executed later (if the promise resolve) in the :

`.then(function (resp) { document.getElementById("app1").innerHTML = resp; });`

To make it short, as soon as you are using "await" the function is "async".